# accepts_nested_attributes causing Stack level too deep in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very basic example

**app/models/user.rb**

```
#name string
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :project,dependent: :destroy
  validates :name,presence: true
  validates_associated :project
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project
end
```

**app/models/project.rb**

```
#name      string
#user_id   integer
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks,dependent: :destroy
  validates :name,presence: true
  validates_associated :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end
```

**app/models/tasks.rb**

```
#name   string
#project_id  integer
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project,dependent: :destroy
  validates :name,presence: true
end
```

That's all I have in model

On the Controller end for **testing** purpose, I have the following code.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def update
    @user.project_attributes = {:name  => "P#rand(100)",:tasks_attributes => [{name: "Task#{rand(100)}"}]}

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Every time, I try to update a given User, I run into `stack level too deep`
problem

Any Clue?

### Note :

```
Rails version 4.0.4 
Ruby 2.1.2p95
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `dependent: :destroy` only in one of models that share an association. If both models have `dependent: :destroy` in 'em, it goes for an infinite number of calls causing **Stack level too deep** error to occur.

Comment: ehh my bad sorry about that and yes you are correct.